# determine type of class member via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, types, type-conversion

I using the following code to determine class member type ,I've seen all the introspection methods but haven't quite figured out how to do it for type such as string ,BigDecimal ,date etc. in my code you can see that i check for primitive and call to method that handle it.
1. I want to do the same for string ,BigDecimal ,fieldTypeName,java.util.Date etc how should i do that ?

1. how this type is called?

for generic type such as jobList i use genericType handler...

```
Object newInstance = clsObj.getClass().newInstance();

                for (Field field : declaredFields) {

                    // Get member name & types

                    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
                    Type genericType = field.getGenericType();
                    String fieldTypeName = fieldType.getName();
                    String memberName = field.getName();

                    boolean primitive = field.getType().isPrimitive();
                    handlePrimtive();
```

> if (genericType instanceof ParameterizedType) {

This is the class

```
@Entity
public class Person {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private int id;
private String firstName;
private BigDecimal bigDecimal;
private java.util.Date myDate;
private List<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<Job>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Class <?> type = field.getType ();
if (String.class.equals (type)) handleString ();
else if (Date.class.equals (type)) handleDate ();
...
```

Comment: there is no generic way to handle it? such as primitive since here i need to ask for every type explicit and Im not sure that i know all the types since this class person is for example but i can get any type of classes with addtional fields...

Comment: @JohnJerrby Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "type such as String, BigDecimal, Date etc", especial what other types go to "etc".  Could you clarify or just list all "such types"?

Comment: This is the problem since i dont know them exactly for instance if the class member is type object i hadnle it with genericType if primitive i use is.primitive to know that but for "other types"  i not sure that  i know all of them thefore i want somehow to diffrantate them,how they called in java this type  String, BigDecimal, Date etc?